# Showing rep for suspended users in mod console is kinda pointless

Tags: discussion, account-suspension, moderator-tools

Showing the rep of users that are in Timed Suspension on the Mod Console is kinda pointless, given that their rep is *always* 1.

[image]

Perhaps there's something more useful that can be displayed here? Perhaps their last annotation on the account or something?

Comment: Or maybe it could show what their rep would be if they weren't suspended?

Comment: I don't think you're going to fit an annotation in that space

Comment: @Michael - yeah, but it's a very skinny table, it could be made wider to fit the annotations